# Encoding video without exec function

Tags: php, encoding, video-player

I use **ffmpeg** to encode videos that i upload to my website, it works fine but the problem is that it requires **exec** function on host enabled, my host provider says enabling this function is a security bug (he talked about shell). i don't want use this function, does anybody know a solution that i can use **ffmpeg** without exec function or any alternate method (using PHP, i want to use it in wordpress)?
thank u very much

Comment: This is not Wordpress related I'm afraid. I've asked for it to be migrated probably to ServerFault.

Comment: i'm looking for pure code or a wordpress based solution

Comment: Probably for StackOverflow then

Comment: yea... think it is kind of related to both of them